# JavaScript: Comparing Values Before and After setTimeout() Anonymous Function

Tags: javascript, settimeout, anonymous-function

I have distilled my question as follows: How do you pass values into an anonymous function in a setTimeout allow a comparison for any changes that have occurred while the function was "waiting"? This will be used to compare a state variable to the value it originally held when the timeout execution was started. Sample Code:

```
 var x = 1;
setTimeout(()=>{ x=2 },2000);
setTimeout(()=>{ console.log(x); },3000);
```

How could I get the second timeout to display 1, the initial value of x so I can compare it to 2, the value of x after the first timeout?  Essentially: how could I pass that initial value in?

Comment: You can't. You need to copy the value into a different variable (in your case: `const y=x;`, then compare `x == y` inside the callback).

Comment: I agree with Bergi that you need another variable.  Initially put the car in first gear.  2 seconds from now, put the car in second gear.  3 seconds from now tell me what gear the car is in.  The code is working fine.  If you want to say "3 seconds from now tell me what gear the car is in and also tell me what gear the car was in when we started" then you'll either need another variable to record "what gear the car was in when we started", or you'll need to simply know (a priori) that it was initialized to the constant 1 and make your comparison to 1.

Comment: Got it!  Thank you both for the feedback.  My issue is that each of these setTimeouts are onChange features of a user selection.  If the user clicks a different option (they are radio inputs), I want to essentially "cancel" the execution of the setTimeout() on the abandoned selection.  This makes it hard to store the variable separately, since they will be different instances of onChange() functions.  I may need to just refactor all of my code here...